# how to know if my control is visible or not

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a dialog containing controls (edits, combobox, etc...) some are visible and some or not.

What in a function, I want is looping on all controls and get the last shown control.

I want to add that when creating the dialog, I set the visibility to some controls as `SW_HIDE` and others to `SW_SHOW`.

What I did is  using the `::IsWindowVisible`, but returns false even if I set the visibility to `SW_SHOW`.

NB: the function is called just after the creation of the dialog, the dialog is not yet visible.

Comment: If you had looked up the [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633530(v=vs.85).aspx), you could answer the question why `IsWindowVisible()` doesn't work as expected: _If the specified window, its parent window, its parent's parent window, and so forth, have the WS_VISIBLE style, the return value is nonzero. Otherwise, the return value is zero._

Comment: In fact that's why I added the last line, because I knwo that the till the dialog is not shown we can't retrieve the SW_SHOW style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The control is *not* visible at the time you call the function, because the dialog that contains it is not visible. As per the documentation for the [`IsWindowVisible` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633530.aspx):

> If the specified window, its parent window, its parent's parent window, and so forth, have the `WS_VISIBLE` style, the return value is nonzero. Otherwise, the return value is zero.

This not only explains the behavior that you're seeing, but also suggests a possible solution. If you want to know whether a particular window has the `WS_VISIBLE` style bit set (and don't care about any of its ancestors), then just retrieve that window's styles and test for the presence of the `WS_VISIBLE` bit directly. For example:

```
LONG_PTR wndStyles = GetWindowLongPtr(hwndCtrl, GWL_STYLE);
bool     isVisible = (wndStyles & WS_VISIBLE) == WS_VISIBLE;
```

That said, I don't really understand why you would need to do this. If your dialog-initialization code sets the visibility of controls, then you *know* what their visibility is. You don't need to retrieve it dynamically at run-time. In other words, this sounds like [an X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I suspect there is a better way to write your code so that this whole issue is a non-issue.

Comment: in fact, i have many dialogs and each one have controls whom's visiblity changes from one dialog to another. and some dialog inhertis controls from others and beside that makes some controls visibles. in fact it's a another person who wrote the code and I have to maintain it.

And I have to knwo the control who is visible and have the greatest RECT.Bottom and this for each dialog, to do resizing, moving etc ..

Comment: Thanx it works. I didn't found that function in other posts.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the answer. This is my code, which I used according to Cody Gray's suggestion. After the ShowWindow(SW_SHOW), the result did not change! In my case the list control is not visible in both cases, possibly it is located outside the dialog bounds.

```
BOOL CDlgOptions::OnInitDialog() {
CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
// TODO:  Add extra initialization here
//db->fillSimpleList(m_lv_dboption);  
RECT rect;

CWnd* w = GetDlgItem(m_lv_dboption.GetDlgCtrlID());
w-> GetClientRect(&rect);
ClientToScreen(&rect);
CString strMsg;
strMsg.Format(L"xt: %d yt: %d xb: %d yb: %d", rect.left, rect.top, 
rect.right, rect.bottom);
MessageBox(strMsg);
HWND h = m_lv_dboption.GetSafeHwnd();
int style{ 0 };
LONG_PTR wndStyles = GetWindowLongPtr(h, style);
wndStyles = (style & WS_VISIBLE);
CString strFormat;
strFormat.Format(L"The listcontrol is %s visible", wndStyles ? L"" : 
L"not");
MessageBox(strFormat);
ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
wndStyles = GetWindowLongPtr(h, style);
wndStyles = (style & WS_VISIBLE);
strFormat.Format(L"The listcontrol is %s visible", wndStyles ? L"": 
L"not");
MessageBox(strFormat);
return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
// EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}
```